# how to transform element then insert into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to python and numpy. I have an numpy array of arrays like so:

```
a = [[  0.      2.      0.     0.      0.      0.   ]
     [  0.     14.      0.     0.      0.      0.   ]]
```

For the first array, where the 2 is, I want to insert 1 0 0, and for the second array where the 14 is, I want to insert 0 0 1, so that the end result looks like the following:

```
a = [[  0.      1.      0.      0.      0.     0.      0.      0.   ]
     [  0.      0.      0.      1.      0.     0.      0.      0.   ]]
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I would use slicing and `place()`, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html

Comment: For `2` you are replacing a value.  For `14` you are replacing a value (with 0) and inserting a (2,2) array.  Two different actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired array has a different shape than the original array, `a`.
Therefore, you can not generate the desired array by using simple slice
assignment, or a single call to assignment functions like `numpy.place`, `numpy.put`, `numpy.putmask`
or `numpy.copyto`.

So instead of regarding this as an assignment-and-insertion operation, I think
it might be better to regard this as construction of a new array.
There are many ways to do this:

- You could use [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

  ```
  np.concatenate([a[:,:1], b, a[:,2:]], axis=1)
  ```
- or [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

  ```
  np.column_stack([a[:,:1], b, a[:,2:]])
  ```
- or [`numpy.c_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

  ```
  np.c_[a[:,:1], b, a[:,2:]]
  ```
- or [`numpy.bmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html):

  ```
  np.array(np.bmat([a[:,:1], b, a[:,2:]]))
  ```
- or allocate space for an empty array and assign values to slices of `c`:

  ```
  c = np.empty((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]+b.shape[1]-1), dtype=a.dtype)
  c[:, :1] = a[:, :1]
  c[:, 1:4] = b
  c[:, 4:] = a[:, 2:]
  ```

  This is not necessary here, but it is good to keep in mind that allocate-and-assign is a viable way to construct arrays. Sometimes, though not here, it is even your fastest option.
- or [`numpy.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) and [`numpy.insert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

  ```
  np.insert(np.delete(a, [1], 1), [1], b, axis=1)
  ```

  I don't recommend using `insert` and `delete` however. The `np.delete` creates a new array with
  values that are copied from `a`. In contrast, the slices `a[:,:1]`, and
  `a[:,2:]` are *views* of `a` so they do not require any copying. The extra
  allocation and copying makes this method slower than the other methods shown
  above.

---

For example, if we define:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[  0.,   2.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,  14.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
b = np.array([(1, 0, 0), 
              (0, 0, 1)])
```

then

```
In [69]: np.concatenate([a[:,:1],b,a[:,2:]], axis=1)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

(The other options produce the same result.)